# Creating a reference can throw a ConcurrentModificationException inside of a transaction with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am making an ancestor query inside of a transaction like this:

```
Task task = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Task.class)
                        .ancestor(jobKey)
                        .filter("locationKey", locationKey)
                        .first().now();
```

Later in the transaction I create and save a new entity that uses the key I used in `ancestor()` as a `Ref<?>` property:

`Task newTask = new Task(jobKey)`

```
// Task POJO with the following property and constructor:
@Parent
private Ref<Job> jobKey;

public Task(Key<Job> jobKey) {
    this.jobKey = Ref.create(jobKey);
}
```

When my whole method runs several times in a second I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on `jobKey`. This is strange to be because all I am doing with it is creating a reference and setting it as a property. I looked at the description of `Ref<?>` and it says:

> Note that the methods might or might not throw runtime exceptions
> related to datastore operations;ConcurrentModificationException,
> DatastoreTimeoutException, DatastoreFailureException, and
> DatastoreNeedIndexException. Some Refs hide datastore operations that
> could throw these exceptions.

Can someone explain to me what is going on with `Ref<?>` and why it is throwing me a `ConcurrentModificationException`? It looks like it is the culprit here.

Answer (score 1):

It's the API of Objectify messing up and misusing the exception system, in order to convey a **retry**.

transactional systems have three major ways to solve a fundamental problem. Imagine this series of commands, all part of a single transaction (written in SQL, assuming it is readable and familiar enough to understand. It's just an example):

```
// transfer 10 bucks from speedy to me
int rBalance = [SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = 'rzwitserloot']
int sBalance = [SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = 'Speedy']
if (sBalance < 10) throw new BalanceInsufficientException();
sBalance -= 10;
rBalance += 10;
[UPDATE accounts SET balance = %rBalance% WHERE user = 'rzwitserloot']
[UPDATE accounts SET balance = %sBalance% WHERE user = 'Speedy']
COMMIT;
```

Seems safe enough right?

No, actually, this is really tricky. Imagine that right in the middle, around `sBalance -= 10;`, you withdraw 50 bucks from your account from an ATM (and your account had 50 bucks to start with).

You are now 50 bucks richer, and your account balance ought to be -10, but it is actually 40.

Whooooops.

Horrible.

There are 3 ways to solve this problem:

1. Locking

Imagine that the transaction locks down the **entire** accounts table the moment I read from it. Nothing else on the planet can write to this table until this transaction is committed. That would solve the problem: Your ATM will just hang for a bit, wait for this balance transfer to complete, and will then do its thing. Actually, it can't even read. What if you read, then this transaction writes a new value? The same problem could occur. So, lock an entire table, for everything, globally.

Solves the problem, but this does not scale.

2. Eh, sod it. Who cares?

Just, don't care about this. Have basic R/W locks or row locks and the bank just loses 50 bucks here. Sounds nuts but many transactional systems work like this. i.e. are broken.

3. Retry

And here comes the magic. A devious way to get the best of both worlds, where the bank cannot possibly mess up and give you 50 free bucks, whilst avoiding lock-the-planet scenarios, is to rerun all queries and doublecheck that the results would be the same.

In this hypothetical scenario, the transactional system has the task of realizing that the `[SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = 'Speedy']` command would now return a different result compared to what it returned earlier, and that this means that the **entire transaction is now invalid**, and needs to be rerun from the top. This solves the problem: The whole block reruns, realizes you now have a  balance of 0, and correctly aborts the attempt to transfer the funds by throwing an `InsufficientBalanceException`. We avoided world locks, at the cost of some bookkeeping and an atomic 'do a quick check if any queries have touched anything that has changed since then' operation on any commit.

**And that is exactly what you are running into here** - that is what objectify means when it throws ConcurrentModificationException. Which is bad API design: That is not the right exception, and in general you shouldn't reuse existing exceptions just because the name sounds like it vaguely matches. But, anyway, you're going to have to live with the fact that objectify made a mistake in this regard.

The general fix is extremely convoluted if you haven't programmed the right way from the start, and it sounds like you haven't.

See, there is this massive problem: That code is not *just* primitives in the db/persistence layer. The db engine **cannot replay the block**. The block contains a bunch of java code, after all!

No, the code itself needs to be told to just start over.

This is then even more complicated. Computers are very reliable machines. If 2 separate processes (Say, the bank web interface where you ordered a fund transfer of 10 bucks to me, and that ATM machine) clash and are both forced to start the command over from scratch, with some bad luck both machines reliably retry and reliably get in each others way a second time, retry yet again, and will continually dovetail together, always forcing each other into retry, forever stuck.

The solution is dice. No really. Daddy needs a new pair of shoes dice. The solution is: If a conflict occurs, wait a random amount of time (but choose from a larger and larger potential pause for each conflict that occurs until something succeeds), thus ensuring that 2 systems will eventually stop dovetailing. Sounds nuts, but without this, you wouldn't be reading this page - this algorithm is a fundamental part of ethernet, which is at the very least powering something at Stack Overflow and/or your house's internet services.

The problem thus becomes that you can't just solve this problem with a while loop. The 'whoops, retry needed' code is complicated.

**The only solution is closures**. All code that interacts with your transactional system must be put inside a lambda, and must be idempotent outside of those parts that modify the data in the storage system (there is no difference between running it once and running it more than once). That way, the framework itself can catch the retry issue, apply the appropriate random exponential backoff, and then start over.

SQL abstractions like JDBI get this right (This is a very large reason why you should never ever write JDBC for real applications. Always use JDBI or JOOQ or something similar). I'm not aware if objectify has such an API. If not you'll have to write it yourself.